# CSS and Fonts advice

Tags: html, css

I am designing an article website and want some samples to look at to choose nice Fonts and CSS. Can you suggest some.

Here are some example of what I am seeking:

- Article Heading Font/Color
- Article Body Font/ Color
- Background Color ideas
- Text Color
- Layout

It will be a two column layout

I thought since most of you are professionals, you can share some sites/resources out of your experience that will make the job easier for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out

[Typetester – Compare fonts for the screen](http://www.typetester.org/)

> The Typetester is an online
>   application for comparison of the
>   fonts for the screen. Its primary role
>   is to make web designer’s life easier.
>   As the new fonts are bundled into
>   operating systems, the list of the
>   common fonts will be updated.

For color scheme layouts this is a nice one

[Color Scheme Designer](http://www.colorschemedesigner.com/)

You can have a live preview of a color scheme.

[kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) from adobe is also a very good site for this

Comment: THanks very useful..Are there are sites that give you some readymade font/color/css combination to look at which I can borrow on my site..

Answer (score 2):

[Common fonts to all versions of Windows & Mac equivalents](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html) is a great resource to see what fonts are likely to be on your visitors' computers.

If you're looking for usability tips, all I can say is *test it out*.  Testing the user's performance for your site is like testing your program's performance.  That is, you need to benchmark.  (It may be more valuable to allocate effort in other areas of your site.)

Comment: @MitMaro, Yes, but if you're using *that* operating system you'd know there are no standard fonts...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will substitute for testing.

A/B Testing with Google Website Optimizer might be useful to measure which fonts or Layouts better produce your desired results.

[TypeTester](http://www.typetester.org/) is pretty nice though - great to narrow down the field of font options.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, check this out for creating nice backgrounds that look like wall papers... I don't know if that is what you want, but it is definitely a resource to keep in your bookmarks/Delicious: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/ribbon/